# Const reference wrapper from reference wrapper

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, constants, template-classes

Consider the following reference wrapper:

```
template <class T>
struct wrapper
{
    wrapper(T& x): reference{x} {}
    void set(const T& x) {reference = x;}
    T& get() const {return reference;}
    T& reference;
};
```

I am wondering:

- How to declare a const reference wrapper through a template alias only `template <class T> using const_wrapper = /* const wrapper<T> or wrapper<const T>?*/`
- How to change the wrapper struct to make the preceding point possible if it is not possible in this state?
- How to solve the following problem: `int i = 42; wrapper<const char> w(i);` will compile but not work (I would like to block the constructor)
- For what exact problem, `iterator` and `const_iterator` general have two different implementations?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `std::reference_wrapper`?

Comment: This example was designed to understand what's going on. If I want a reference wrapper, I would use std::reference_wrapper.

Comment: _"How to declare a const reference wrapper through a template alias only `template <class T> using const_wrapper = /* const wrapper<T> or wrapper<const T>?*/`"_ Do you mean a const (reference wrapper) or a (const reference) wrapper? Or even const (const reference) wrapper?

Comment: Another question: What do you expect your const reference wrapper to do when `set(const T&)` is called?

Comment: @SimonKraemer: set(const T&) should set the referenced value.

Comment: @Vincent: Do you mean that it would be equivalent to `get() = x`? Because by definition, you cannot modify something that is `const`.

Comment: What does the last question mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to declare a const reference wrapper through a template alias only template `<class T> using const_wrapper = /* const wrapper<T> or wrapper<const T>?*/`

Obviously that would be:

```
template <class T> using const_wrapper = wrapper<const T>;
```

The contained type is `const`, not the wrapper.

Be advised however that your `set` function cannot be called if `T` is `const`. This is for obvious reasons; you can't change a `const` value.

> How to solve the following problem: `int i = 42; wrapper<const char> w(i);` will compile but not work (I would like to block the constructor)

This is actually a bit complicated. What you have to do is cause compilation to fail if the user tries to use a type that does not exactly match `T`. To do that, you need to use the `=delete` feature of C++11:

```
template <class T>
struct wrapper
{
    wrapper(T& x): reference{x} {}
    template<typename U>
        wrapper(const U &) = delete;
    //...
};
```

That second constructor will be used when anyone passes a type that is not an exact match for `T`. And since it is `delete`d, you get a compiler error when people attempt to use it.

> For what exact problem, iterator and const_iterator general have two different implementations?

Who says that they do? They are not even required to be *different* types (consider the iterators for `set` for example), let alone required to have different *implementations*. They are simply distinct type aliases.

Comment: I don't think that `wrapper<const T>;` is correct. You can't update a reference itself (see the comments about `set(const T&)`). If this is what OP wants to do he needs to change the code to using a pointer as member - as `std::reference_wrapper` does.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: He wanted to know how to apply `const` to the type contained by his container; what I posted will do that. I never claimed that all of the functions defined in his container would still *work*. Also, it's not clear what he actually wants his `set` function to do.

Comment: `vector<const int>` isn't allowed, I think. `set<int>` is a better example.

Answer (score 0):

> - How to declare a const reference wrapper through a template alias only `template <class T> using const_wrapper = /* const wrapper<T> or wrapper<const T>?*/`

It depends what you want it to mean, which you haven't made clear.

> - How to change the wrapper struct to make the preceding point possible if it is not possible in this state?

See above.

> - How to solve the following problem: `int i = 42; wrapper<const char> w(i);` will compile but not work (I would like to block the constructor)

Add a partial specialization

```
template <class T>
struct wrapper<const T>
{
    wrapper(const T& x): reference{x} {}
    wrapper(T&) = delete;
    void set(const T& x) {reference = x;}
    const T& get() const {return reference;}
    const T& reference;
};
```

Or add a suitably constrained constructor to the primary template:

```
template <class T>
struct wrapper
{
    wrapper(T& x): reference{x} {}
    template<typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_const<T>{} && std::is_same<T, const U>{}, void>>
    wrapper(U&) = delete;
    void set(const T& x) {reference = x;}
    T& get() const {return reference;}
    T& reference;
};
```

> - For what exact problem, `iterator` and `const_iterator` general have two different implementations?

Generally it should be possible to implicitly convert `iterator` to `const_iterator` but not the other way around. So you either need a SFINAEd constructor that only exists for the `const_iterator` form, or you have two implementations, one that supports the extra conversion and one that doesn't.

Using SFINAE wasn't an option in C++98, so most standard library implementations (which were written long before Expression SFINAE was available) use two separate implementations.

Answer (score -1):

By the assumption that `set` should change the value of the referenced object and not the reference itself:

```
template <class T>
struct wrapper
{
    wrapper(T& x) : reference{ x } {}

    template<typename U> 
    wrapper(U& x) : reference{ x } {} //<- Possible answer for question 3

    //template<typename U>
    //wrapper(U& x) = delete; //<- Possible answer for question 3

    void set(const T& x) const { reference = x; } //<- Answer for question 2
    T& get() const { return reference; }

    T& reference;
};

template <class T>
using const_wrapper = const wrapper<T>; //<- Answer for question 1


int main()
{
    //Testing const_wrapper
    char a;
    const_wrapper<char> b(a);
    b.set('a');

    //Testing narrowing cast
    int i = 42; 
    wrapper<const char> w(i);   //error C2397: conversion from 'int' to 'const char' requires a narrowing conversion
                                //error C2280 : 'wrapper<const char>::wrapper<int>(U &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
    //w.set('b'); //error C3490: 'reference' cannot be modified because it is being accessed through a const object
}
```

For your last question I can't give you a satisfying answer. This is pretty much an implemention detail. <s>I can't think of any general case where `iterator` and `const_iterator` are not at least inheriting one another - the non-const-version extending the const version.</s>

*Update:* The last part might be a MSVC specific implementation detail. I still find it reasonable to inherit `iterator` from `const_iterator`, yet this should be pointed out.

Comment: I can't think of any cases where `const_iterator` inherits from `iterator`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely The other way around. "the non-const-version extending the const version." So `iterator` inheriting from `const_iterator`

Comment: I have never seen that done either, so I can think of **many** cases where they "are not at least inheriting one another".

Comment: @JonathanWakely e.g. the MSVC implementation of `std::string::iterator`. The types are defined as  `typedef typename _Mybase::iterator iterator;` and `typedef typename _Mybase::const_iterator const_iterator;`. `_MyBase` is `_String_alloc` and there we have `typedef _String_iterator<_String_val<_Val_types> > iterator;` and `typedef _String_const_iterator<_String_val<_Val_types> > const_iterator;`. And `_String_iterator` is defined as `template<class _Mystr>
 class _String_iterator
  : public _String_const_iterator<_Mystr>`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Also it does make sense to make `iterator` inherit `const_iterator` so you can pass an object of type `iterator` as parameter where a `const_iterator` is expected. And you don't have duplicate code. You just have to add the non-const functions.

Comment: @JonathanWakely This might of course be Microsoft specific detail. I will change the last part accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely specific to that implementation, and not common to all standard library implementations, or other container libraries in general.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Good to know. Is there any reason this isn't done by default?

Comment: @SimonKraemer: Because it's an implementation detail and different implementations are implemented differently.